# Downloading documents via interacting with a form using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, download

I am currently writing a script for extracting all pdf files from an inbox and placing them into a google drive.

A specific company always supplies an access code in the body of the email along with a url where one can go download the pdf. This is simple for a human to do. However, I am attempting to do this automatically via a script. I have chosen to use `selenium` in Python, however, I am open to other tools as well. Note that this is the first time using `selenium` but I have studied a good part of the documentation.

In part 1, we setup the driver and access the url as follows:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


acc_code = 'acc_code'
url = 'https://u23097853.ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?upn=s89yYpUOqEGMyIeruW2FCK2WfH9LMJ9NSHjmBRTi0csdJBXzTfn-2FZ8aGHS-2B0FM6mX3Okr-2BvBrgK2BheYMDIaWrVYb3ROOdvcTJPZLNJIRGRBrSKyaG-2BUskPAlXKhPHvHiWyGYRTphMK9sa32odQbkRQ6tDjWCb-2F-2F1d8lt9LvD0GImTPoFfD3GHpx88zIEtMMaBGXpGhkhLtnoc23FRWeWg-3D-3DdhyO_ZP9l7R3x3NBEnnPwlhIdwsX64Tg-2BufqUiDhRI6Yt-2BHQtpNZhaYYJVX4TWCYJHKAv31lLD1VZJcdKPHHrxyp3JOp18lHsGa9y2musmmCO3yICtqs81XYZl4GxIWCl27B0xhunVaPaVrqg1zCxvjiBqR563TZLEQLmcN-2FMDXFMiFhArIZP3ltf5K-2F2V2xGpf5U6Q7xsEhaluvppcTewqw43Sh1zMmm4aflt7wVhyWxc14-3D'

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # No window to display
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", 
    {
    "download.default_directory": "C:/Users/'Local User'/Documents/Python_scripts/email_filter/downloads/",
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False, "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}],
    "download.extensions_to_open": "applications/pdf"
    }
)
# Start the Chrome browser with configured options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
```

Note that I have given the actual url so you are welcome to load it. As I have disabled the `headless` argument, it opens a chrome window and loads the following page:

[image: url_page]

I now inspect the page to find out where to place the account code. I then want to submit it by clicking the "Validate" button.

[image: url_page_html]

The following code manages to to that:

```py
password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "accessCode")
password.send_keys(acc_code)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@class="btn btn-secondary"]')
button.click()
# Take you to next page
current_url = driver.current_url
```

We are now taken to the download page

[image: download_page]

This is where I get a bit stuck. I am able to access the download button as well as the script that performs the download. The button seems to be here:

[image: button]

The JavaScript function seems to be here:

[image]

My two options for performing the download as as follows:

```py
# Option 1:
button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.btnContainer .btn-secondary')
button.click()


# Option 2:
driver.execute_script("SaveFromIFrame();")  # runs the actual javascript function
```

This seems to perform the download. However, it still requires me to name the file via opening a window.

[image]

This seems a bit odd as I thought that I disabled prompts. Furthermore, if I use `chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")` then no download happens. This is probably because the script gets stuck at that phase where the pdf needs to be named and downloaded as in the above image.

I believe I am doing something wrong along the way. Please help me identify the issue. Lastly, I would like to run this function as a  Google Cloud function such that downloading it to a local directory is not possible. Are there any alternatives to this such as downloading the bytes of the file to a `io.BytesIO`?

Comment: Have you seen this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61998139/19813684)? Or perhaps [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63093991/19813684) might help.  Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76694658/19813684) answer.